# edit and update the row in database using django

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(
            self, self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email, self.age)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author=models.ForeignKey(Author)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0} {1} {2}".format(
            self.pk, self.book_name, self.publisher_name)
```

forms.py

```
class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author     

BookFormset = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, 
    fields=('book_name', 'publisher_name'), extra=1, 
    can_delete=False)
```

urls.py is

```
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^$', index),
    url('^index/$', index),
    url('^addbook/$', addbook),
    url('^book_detail/$', book_detail, 'book_summary'),
    url('^editbook/(?P<book_id>\d+)/$', editbook) ,
    url('^deletebook/(?P<book_id>\d+)/$',deletebook) ,


    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),


)
```

I need to perform edit and update the row in database,i did it by using single table.But using  two table have some confusion how to take 2nd table using that particular id.I am using forms in this.Can you help me in this to write codes in views.py.Example for doing the same using two table is no where i seen.

Thanks

Comment: can anyone check and tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def update_book(request, book_id):
    author = get_object_or_404(Author, pk=author_id)

    form = AuthorForm(instance=author)
    book_formset = BookFormset(instance=author)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthorForm(request.POST, instance=author)
        if form.is_valid():
            author = form.save(commit=False)
            book_formset = BookFormset(request.POST, instance=author)
            if book_formset.is_valid():
                author.save()
                book_formset.save()
                return redirect('/index/')

    return render_to_response('updatebook.html',{
        'form': form, 'formset': book_formset
    },context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 


<div align="center">
    <tr>
        <form method="POST"> 
            {% csrf_token %} 
            <h5>Author:</h5>
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <h5>Book:</h5>
            {{ formset.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: hi small doubt, in author table,no author_id field but in the code mentioned as author = get_object_or_404(Author, pk=author_id)

Comment: author_id is not a field, it's a variable that you need to pass in the update. So that the object will know which data must be update

Comment: Your url for update has the capability also to pass the id in that view

Comment: the answer was right,but while i am clicking the submit button,it is giving "Page not found" error,any sujection on this

Comment: remember the id? Your url needs an id, don't forget.

Comment: hi i updated the urls.py,i am not able to get the id.How to do that.Any solution please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26166/discussion-between-user2161650-and-catherine)